# How to hide progress bar after 10 seconds in Android?

Tags: android, visibility, android-progressbar

I am working on `Android`. I want to show the progress bar only for 10 seconds after the connection to `www.google.com` is success. Here is my code. Any help is appreciated.

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button1;
    Public ProgressBar mProgress;
    progressCheck obj = new progressCheck(mProgress);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Button fab = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mProgress =(ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                    obj.execute();
            }
        });


    }
```

**ProgressCheck.java extends AsyncTask**

```
   import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import java.io.IOException;

public class progressCheck  extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    public progressCheck(ProgressBar p){
        this.mProgressBar = p;
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        Document doc = null;
        String url = "https://www.google.com.pk/";
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(20 * 1000).get();
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... text) {


    }

}
```

**Content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.namal.circularprogressbar2.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:indeterminate="false" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="72dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You either need a callback from your `AsyncTask` or give it a reference to your `ProgressBar` so it can disable it when done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set Visibility to Visible in onPreExecute() and to Gone to in onPostExecute()

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
     mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    mProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

EDIT: Define progressbar in your `AsyncTask`.

```
ProgressBar mProgress;
```

Make constructor for your Asynctask and pass progressbar reference to it.

```
public progressCheck(ProgressBar progressbar){
   this.mProgress = progressbar;
```

}

And in your activity call it `progressCheck obj = new progressCheck(mProgress);`

EDIT2: MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button1;
Public ProgressBar mProgress;
progressCheck obj;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button fab = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mProgress =(ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    obj = new progressCheck(mProgress);
    mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                obj.execute();
        }
    });


}
```

Comment: The AsyncTask is in a separate class so, you cannot directly reference `mProgress` from it

Comment: @Vygintas B  `mProgress` is initiated in the `MainActivity` while `onPostExecute(String result)` and `onPreExecute()` are in `AsyncTask` class. Your suggestion cannot work.

Comment: @Shaishav Definitely. Any other way round?

Comment: See my EDIT @waqas

Comment: @VygintasB See the updated code. It is not working. `progressCheck obj = new progressCheck(mProgress);` is not initiated.

Comment: Because you need to initiate your progressBar before you initiate your AsyncTask. Call `progressCheck obj = new progressCheck(mProgress);`  after you initiate your progressbar @waqas

Comment: @VygintasB I did that. See the code. But now `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ProgressBar.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference` is detected.

Comment: SEE my EDIT2. This should be correct order you need to initiate. You need to initiate object before using it. @waqas

Comment: @VygintasB Thanks buddy.. My Bad.. Thanks buddy.

Comment: Happy to help. Accept answer if it fixed your problem @waqas

Comment: Sure my dear. @VygintasB

Answer (score 1):

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pd.setTitle("Please wait");
        pd.setMessage("Connecting to Google...");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try{
           Thread.sleep(YOUR_TIME);
        } 
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) 
    {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        if (pd!=null && pd.isShowing())
        {
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    }
}.execute();
```

Now manage with your requirement..
Hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

Remove `mProgress` lines form onClick() method.

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                    obj.execute(); 
            }
        });
```

And add these mProgress visibility line in onPreExecute() method and mProgress Gone in onPostExecute() method.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
   mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
   mProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

**EDIT**

pass mProgress to the progressCheck class.

```
progressCheck obj = new progressCheck(mProgress);
```

and get it in progressCheck constructor.

```
ProgressBar progress;
public progressCheck(ProgressBar mProgress){
   progress = mProgress;
}
```

And the Async ovrridden methods be like...

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
     progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: The AsyncTask is in a separate class so, you cannot directly reference `mProgress` from it

Comment: you can simply pass `mProgress` to `progressCheck`  class or you can directly code the class `progressCheck` in `MainActivity`.

Comment: Don't comment here, make an edit to your answer so the OP (and future visitors) may know.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is in your AsyncTask onPostExecute  write this code.

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run () {
        // Do your stuff here  -- show your progress bar 
    }
}
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 10000);
```

complete code

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import java.io.IOException;

public class progressCheck  extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        Document doc = null;
        String url = "https://www.google.com.pk/";
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(20 * 1000).get();
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run () {
        // Do your stuff here  -- show your progress bar 
    }
}
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 10000);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... text) {


   }
}
```

Comment: `mProgress` is initiated in the `MainActivity` while `onPostExecute(String result)` and `onPreExecute()` are in `AsyncTask `class. Your suggestion cannot work.